# Qt C++ - Aligning QProgressBar inside a QSplashScreen

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am putting a `QProgressBar` inside a `QSplashScreen` by subclassing QSplashScreen.  It overrides the `drawContents()` method.

I thought I had set the geometry correctly, but it renders at both the top and bottom of the screen.  I don't know why.  Perhaps there's another way to align it.  The numbers are correct, as the image is 380x284, so a 19 height progress bar should be 265 pixels down.

Sorry for crappy picture, splash screen wasn't showing up with print screen button.  It's just a 1 color white splash screen at the moment, but as you can see, progress bar at top and bottom (they're both the same colors, its the lighting from the camera).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEtWk.jpg

Another issue will be the `showMessage()` method of QSplashScreen.  I want the message to appear above the progress bar, right-aligned... if anyone has any ideas how to do that.

splashscreen.cpp

```
#include "splashscreen.h"

SplashScreen::SplashScreen(QApplication *app, QWidget *parent) :
    QSplashScreen(parent)
{
    this->app = app;

    this->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/splashscreen.png"));
    this->setCursor(Qt::BusyCursor);

    // if I dont make it a child, it *only* renders at the top
    progress = new QProgressBar(this); 
    progress->setGeometry(0, 265, 380, 19); // puts it at bottom
    progress->setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter);
    progress->setValue(0);
    progress->setMaximum(100);
    progress->setEnabled(true);

    this->showMessage("Hello", Qt::AlignBottom);

    connect(progress, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(progressBarUpdated(int)));
}

void SplashScreen::drawContents(QPainter *painter)
{
    QSplashScreen::drawContents(painter);
    this->progress->render(painter);
}

void SplashScreen::progressBarUpdated(int value)
{
    this->repaint();
    this->app->processEvents();
}
```

splashscreen.h

```
#ifndef SPLASHSCREEN_H
#define SPLASHSCREEN_H

#include <QSplashScreen>
#include <QProgressBar>
#include <QApplication>

class SplashScreen : public QSplashScreen
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SplashScreen(QApplication *app, QWidget *parent = 0);
    QProgressBar *progress;
    QWidget *spacer;
    QApplication *app;

public slots:
    void progressBarUpdated(int value);

protected:
    void drawContents(QPainter *painter);

};

#endif // SPLASHSCREEN_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <time.h>

#include "splashscreen.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    srand(time(0));
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    SplashScreen *splash = new SplashScreen(&a);
    splash->show();

    // snip.. loading a ton of stuff into memory at startup 
    // if you're testing this you might have to sleep/timer here iono

    MainWindow w;
    splash->finish(&w);
    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can paint progress directly, without creating QProgressBar. For example:

sp.h:

```
#ifndef SPLASHSCREEN_H
#define SPLASHSCREEN_H

#include <QSplashScreen>
#include <QApplication>

class SplashScreen : public QSplashScreen
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SplashScreen(QApplication *app, QWidget *parent = 0);
    int m_progress;
    QApplication *app;

public slots:
    void setProgress(int value)
    {
      m_progress = value;
      if (m_progress > 100)
        m_progress = 100;
      if (m_progress < 0)
        m_progress = 0;
      update();
    }

protected:
    void drawContents(QPainter *painter);

};

#endif // SPLASHSCREEN_H
```

sp.cpp

```
#include "sp.h"

SplashScreen::SplashScreen(QApplication *aApp, QWidget *parent) :
    QSplashScreen(parent), app(aApp), m_progress(0)

{
    this->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/splashscreen.png"));
    this->setCursor(Qt::BusyCursor);

    this->showMessage("Hello", Qt::AlignBottom);
}

void SplashScreen::drawContents(QPainter *painter)
{
  QSplashScreen::drawContents(painter);

  // Set style for progressbar...
  QStyleOptionProgressBarV2 pbstyle;
  pbstyle.initFrom(this);
  pbstyle.state = QStyle::State_Enabled;
  pbstyle.textVisible = false;
  pbstyle.minimum = 0;
  pbstyle.maximum = 100;
  pbstyle.progress = m_progress;
  pbstyle.invertedAppearance = false;
  pbstyle.rect = QRect(0, 265, 380, 19); // Where is it.

  // Draw it...
  style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ProgressBar, &pbstyle, painter, this);
}
```

May be this helps you.

Comment: Any `python` implementation?